# Is it possible to beat the Assembler today?

Tags: optimization, assembly, gpu

Apparently it used to be, according to this [terrific account by Ed Nather](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html).  How about today?  That is, is it possible, with enough knowledge of CPU/FPU/GPU/etc. architecture, to write machine code that is more efficient than what would be produced by a mainstream assembler (nasm, GAS, etc.), in any scenario?  How about for GPU kernels?

**EDIT**: "Not constructive"?  Please.  This question produced @Pointy's answer, which was quite enlightening to anyone not that familiar with how assemblers work. Someone has favorited it.  The fact that Pointy is, endearingly, one of the close-voters is a nice touch but hey if it's the best answer it gets accepted.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you could elaborate in an Answer that would be great. :)

Comment: Re the 'Not constructive' close vote--if someone supplies a clear case of how to do such an optimization this question is *very* constructive.  And worth a try in any case.

Comment: Every assembler I've ever seen has made it possible to produce any arrangement of bits desired in each memory location of a program. That's the whole point of an assembler. That story looks apocryphal to me and I basically don't believe it. Even if it were true, there's no reason to claim it has anything to do with the difference between "machine language" and "assembly language".

Comment: @DanielFischer in particular, what is it that you'd be able to do arranging the contents of a code segment that categorically could not be done with an assembler?

Comment: @Pointy As with Daniel Fischer's (completely opposite) answer, please elaborate and put it in an Answer.  I've done some assembly but don't know that much about the scope of what you can do with an Assembler in all scenarios--allocating RAM seems like something that it typically does for you for example.

Comment: Oh, wait, are you talking about the assembly -> machine code step? I thought of assembly production, mostly. Of course you can make the assembler produce whatever machine code you want, as far as I know.

Comment: @Pointy Reading your comment, I think I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer understandable; I thought it was about beating an optimizing compiler at first.

Comment: @Pointy So what's changed since 1959?

Comment: @DanielFischer Same q as ^

Comment: @MattPhillips to the extent that you can actually take that story as factual, even it doesn't make the claim that the programmer was able to do what was allegedly done only via machine code.

Comment: @MattPhillips - While certainly an interesting topic of discussion, this question is pretty much the definition of "Not Constructive" for Stack Overflow.  SO is intended to be a database of how to do *thing*, and your question is more intended to elicit debate and discussion - more appropriate for a web forum or a chatroom than for SO.

Comment: @Joe Put the quoted phrase "Is it possible" into the SO search box, hit enter, and see what happens.  Questions of this general form are legion.  This one in fact has (it has emerged) a very clear, concrete answer.  What's left to chat about?  Your appraisal is completely wrong.

Comment: @MattPhillips - You're more than welcome to start a discussion on [meta] if you wish, but ten people (the five who voted, plus all five who reviewed the reopen vote) disagreed.  Note the text of the close reason: `As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion`  That's exactly what this is intended to do.  Again, I think it's an interesting topic for discussion, but not a SO question.

Comment: @Joe "That's exactly what this is intended to do."  Umm, actually as the author of the question I can tell you that the intention of the question was to get exactly what it did get, a clear, informative answer like Pointy's, which was echoed by 2/3 others.  I'm sure it's fun to pile on and close-vote a question once the first few start coming in--I have the privilege myself--but this was a miscarriage.  Optimization questions about C -> assembly are asked all the time.

Comment: @Joe I'm guessing it's because I mentioned Nather's story--then 'Look, this guy has something 'fun' in his question!  Hey we get to close it now right?'  Actually 'The story of Mel' was brought up purely as a precedent to motivate the question.  (It's factual afaik.)  Lol whatever at least this sort of thing happens very rarely.  Yes, this probably belongs in Meta at this point but I don't really have anything else to say so that won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. There's no single thing called "assembly language".  An assembler is a program that translates a textual encoding of instructions for a particular architecture into a form suitable for execution.  Exactly what facilities a particular assembler exposes is up to its designer. Many CPU architectures have several assemblers available.
2. Because an assembler's job is to provide a "friendly" way for a person to request a precise sequence of machine instructions (and other aspects of a program, such as initialized memory locations, reserved blocks of storage, directives to the runtime executive, etc), if it's possible to produce a program by hand that can't be produced by some particular assembler then that really only means you've got an inadequate assembler. The assembler that Intel developed for the iAPX 86 series (not Microsoft's *masm*, which was a weak imitator) had a fairly typical macro facility, and it also had a sort of "micro macro" facility that would allow the dictionary of opcode mnemonics (things like `MOV`, `ADD`, `BNE`, etc) to be extended arbitrarily.  With an assembler like that, it would clearly be possible to create any piece of code you desired.

The real topic for concern in programming is whether burdening the programmer with the responsibility for choosing a strategy for getting work done by a computer in extreme detail is worthwhile for performance.  The question of course has no single answer, because there are many possible situations, many different computing devices, and mostly because things change all the time. In 1959, for example, the computing task of translating a higher-level language like FORTRAN into machine code was *itself* a significant workload for computers. Understanding of how programming languages should even work was in its infancy.

Today, then, the only reason to know "machine language" (and note that the word "language" isn't really accurate) is to create an instruction sequence when there's no available (or convenient) assembler.  That's assuming that explicitly creating a particular instruction sequence is better than using a higher-level language for some reason. Even then, it's generally the case that if you were doing that now you'd be writing software in some high-level language to emit the chosen instruction sequence; that is, you'd effectively create a "domain-specific assembler" for some task. A good example would be the code in something like a virtual machine interpreter that builds machine language blocks on-the-fly, like a Java or JavaScript VM.

Comment: Nice answer.  You're also the star of the edit to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

The assembler takes assembly language and turns it into machine code.  Ideally, but not always the case the assembly language has a one to one relationship with the machine code instruction.  *MOST* of the time the translation from assembly language syntax for an instruction and the machine code will be identical whether the assembler does it or if it is done by hand.  naturally there are some dont care bits from time to time and the assembler and human may choose different dont care bits so the result doesnt have to be a bit for bit match but lengthwise and speedwise they will be identical, no difference at all.

The differences between the human and the assembler software will be, if any, where the assembly language is not a one to one relationship with the machine code, and/or for various reasons the programmer wants the assembler to take care of something.  This could be pseudo instructions, or macros, or things having to do with externally defined variables.

Assembly language is a loaded term as it is defined by the particular assembler, you can have many different and non-compatible assembly languages for the same processor.  And you can have assembly languages where there are instances where the language does not completely describe all the information needed to choose the specific instruction, near vs far jumps for example for some instruction sets with some assemblers.

So if you want to compare apples to apples there will be no difference between hand assembled code and software assembled code.  Apples to apples meaning the code in question is written properly to not be vague so the software and the human assemblers can assemble it.  If you do find differences other than dont care bits, then it probably has to do with an optimization which has to do with the human assembler *changing* the code, to make it fair the matching assembly language can/should be changed to match.  This difference would have nothing to do with human vs assembly language assemblers, but one programmers program as compared to anothers.  Basically you could/would get the same result in assembly language with the software assembler.

Answer (score 0):

A skilled assembly-language programmer *who is targeting a very specific run-time environment* can probably produce code which will run better than a compiler would produce.  Depending upon the nature of the code, the performance improvement may or may not be significant relative to the amount of work required.

On the other hand, frameworks such as Java or .NET allow a programmer to compile software to an "intermediate" form which can, on demand, be translated into machine code which includes specific optimizations for the environment where it's actually running.  Code which is compiled to run on "any platform", when run by framework engine which was hand-tweaked for the platform it's running on, may not run as well as assembly code that was hand-tweaked for that platform, but better than code which was hand-tweaked to optimize performance on some other platform.

Comment: Thank you but actually I think you've misunderstood the question, see the comments below it.

Comment: Same general situation may apply, still.  Someone who is generating ARM machine-code bytes by hand may want to store a byte with a certain value to a register and realize that the lower 8 bits of program counter will happen to have the right value in just the right place to allow use of "STRB R15,[0]".  Of course, if the code needs to move, everything breaks.

Answer (score 0):

"Apparently it used to be, according to this terrific account by Ed Nather. "

I remember reading a story like that decades ago. 
It's been doing the rounds for a long time.

The blackjack bit is an embellishment but the code dropping out at the right point and the weeks spent trying to figure out how it worked before the penny finally dropped definitely rings a very old bell